# EXC_BAD_ACCESS in location based app

Tags: exc-bad-access, cllocationmanager

My app uses Location Manager. I see the above error after the updateService is stopped, and the delegate is set to nil. Here's the code:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{
     NSLog(@"location latitude %f",  newLocation.coordinate.latitude);
     NSLog(@"location longitude %f", newLocation.coordinate.longitude);

     if (<app-specific-location-trigger) {
      if (ivSignificantChangesModeUsed) 
         [[self myLocMgr] stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
      else
         [[self myLocMgr] stopUpdatingLocation];     

     [[self myLocMgr] setDelegate:nil];
     self.myLocMgr = nil;
     [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
     }
     NSLog(@"leaving didUpdateToLocation: method");
}
```

Here is what is on the console:

```
![2011-09-01 17:27:31.245   Latitude: 37.754280
2011-09-01 17:27:31.245   Longitude: -122.197792
2011-09-01 17:27:32.051   leaving didUpdateToLocation: method
 
(gdb) continue
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
(gdb)][1]
```

Here's what's shown in the debug view...

All help is appreciated.

Thanks,
-S-

Comment: why are you niling `self.myLocMgr`?

Comment: I was instantiating it when the user set the app-trigger.  However, i removed the statement that nil'ed the locMgr in addition to instantiating in viewDidLoad() method.   The error is gone.    Thanks.

Comment: @DanielA.White You should post that as the answer and Sam should accept it. Only fair right?

Comment: I will gladly do so...     @DanielA.White - please post it as an answer. (9/20/2011)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why are you niling `self.myLocMgr`? (This is requested by the OP)